# Hardware Router For macOS

Tags: network, wifi, firewall, router, modem

I "think" I understand that all firewalls are software. However, I am splitting the monthly internet bill with a roommate who has the ISP modem/router in his room. I would like add (if possible) more security measures. (I cannot get my own ISP in my room; as the house is designated as a “heritage house” and the landlord won’t agree to any “drilling”).
I have my macOS firewall turned on to “block all incoming connections”. I also use Tunnel Bear VPN.

Are there any recommendations (hardware or software) available considering my situation?

Comment: I fail to see how a hardware solution has anything to do with macOS.

Comment: @JMY1000 - technically speaking, the [Airport Express](https://www.apple.com/airport-express/) or the [Airport Extreme](https://www.apple.com/airport-extreme/) would classify as a "hardware solution" in this scenario.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not seem Apple specific  it would be the same for a windows pc.

Comment: @Mark - there are many things in the Apple-verse that would also apply to a Windows PC; that in and of itself doesn't make it off topic.

Comment: What is your goal/intention here, what do you want to improve/prevent?

Comment: @patrix: I want as much security as is reasonably affordable.

Comment: @Mark & Jimmy: to what forum does this question belong? I am new.

Comment: Security isn‘t absolute, so it might help to know which specific dangers you want to protect against and what reasonable means for you. Also this probably isn‘t really on-topic here, so instead of reposting the Q on a more appropriate site I can migrate it there for you.

Comment: SuperUser seems the most appropriate candidate at the moment, but please amend the question first to make it more specific. Otherwise it might get closed over there as well.

Comment: @patrix: Allan answered my question. I wanted to know if there was a hardware device that I could employ to add an extra layer of security. However, the only option is to have physical access to the router which I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more security than what you have now, you could add a hardware based router/firewal between your roommates Internet connected network and  your "network"

What you would be doing is connecting your WAN port of your router to your roommates LAN.  This will create a "double NAT" network, where your roommate becomes your ISP.

The benefit this has over a highly configured firewall is that the router will immediately block all incoming traffic (by default) on the roommates LAN but allow you egress to the Internet.